# Using pipe between diffrent programs how ?

Tags: c, linux

Question asked again and code modified...

I need to create three programs named as program0 program1 and program2 in linux.

Program0:Creates a parent with two child processes and executes program 1 and program 2 with its childs waits them to finish and close.

Program1:Takes a file name from the user and writes text to the file.It finishes writing when CTNL+D pressed and creates a pipe.After that by using cat command it writes file to stdout and uses dup() to create pipe which has file in it.

Program2:It reads filename from the pipe  with the help of dup() and then executes wc command.

So far I managed to create all programs and I have no compling errors.Program 0 executes both programs.Program1 is also working and sends file to the pipe but program2 cannot read it from the pipe is prints weird symbols..

When I try to read from the pipe within the program1 it works(see the deactivated code in program1) but same code is not working if I put it inside program2.

So what  how can I make program2 to read from the pipe after that I will try to execute wc command in program2 but first I should be able to see that its taking file input from the stdout so how?

I know its kinda long but please help me guys...

Program 0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 999

int main()
{
pid_t pid1, pid2;

pid1 = fork();
if(pid1<0) 
{
fprintf(stderr,"Fork basarisiz");
exit(-1);
}
else if (pid1 ==0)/*child prosesleri*/
{


printf("program1\n");

execlp("./program1","program1",NULL);
execlp("./program2","program2",NULL);
}
else /*parent procsesleri */
{
wait(NULL);
pid2 = fork();
if(pid2<0) 
{
fprintf(stderr,"Fork basarisiz");
exit(-1);
}
else if (pid2 ==0)/*child prosesleri*/
{
printf("\n");
printf("Program 2\n");
printf("\n");
execlp("./program2","program2",NULL);
//printf("\n");
}
else
{
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
wait(NULL);
printf("\n");
printf("Parent:Two child processes have successfully been created\n");
printf("Parent:Two child processes have successfully been terminated\n");
printf("Parent:This process will now terminate\n");
printf("\n");
exit(0);
}
}
```

Program 1

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX 999

int main() 
{ 
    char c[10000];              
    char file[10000];
    int words;
    printf("Child1:A text file will be created\n");
    printf("Child1:Enter the name of the file\n");
    scanf("%123s",file);
    strcat(file,".txt"); 
    FILE * pf; 
    pf = fopen(file, "w" );

   if (!pf)
   fprintf( stderr, "I couldn't open the file.\n" );

   else
   {
        printf("Child1: Input a number of text lines ended, each ended by a CR (carriage return).\n");


/////////////////////////////

  do
{
  if (NULL != fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin))
  {
    if (0 == strcmp(c, ".\n")) 
    {
      break;
    }

    fprintf(pf, "%s", c);
  }
  else
  {
    if (0 != ferror(stdin))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "An error occured while reading from stdin\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Child1: Finish the input by CNTL^D\n");
    }

    break;
  }
} while (1);

/////////////////////////////

    }
    printf("\nChild1:The file %s is succesfully created and saved in the current dictionary\n",file);


//////////////////////////////////////////////



/////////////////////////pipe///////////////

    fclose(pf);  // close file  

        char ch;
        int outcount = 0;
        int     fd[2], nbytes;
        pid_t   childpid;
int i;
        char f2[2];

        char    readbuffer[80];

        pipe(fd);

        if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
        {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }

        if(childpid == 0)

        {       printf("\nChild1:The file written to pipe with cat\n");
                close(1) ;
                dup(fd[1]);
                close(fd[0]);
                execlp("/bin/cat", "cat", file,NULL);

        }
        else
        {
            wait(NULL);  
            //close(0) ; 
            //dup(fd[0]) ;
            //close(fd[1]);
            //nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));

            //printf("%s\n",readbuffer);
        }

        return(0);
}
```

Program 2

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() 
{ 
        int   fd[2],nbytes;
        pid_t   childpid;
        char    readbuffer[80];

        pipe(fd);

        if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
        {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }

        if(childpid == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            close(0) ; 
            dup(fd[0]) ;
            close(fd[1]);
            nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
            printf("%s\n",readbuffer);

        }

        return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the man pages for **execve(2)** (for starting `cat`) and **dup2(2)** (for overriding `stdin` and `stdout` as needed) for this one.  `execve` will overwrite the currently executing program by a different one (same PID, same file descriptors), while `dup2` will allow you re-define any of the standard file descriptors to point into any file descriptor you provide to it (such as any of the ends of your pipe).

Comment: but starting and terminating programs are controlled by program0 and its working fine so I didnt understand your comments about execve(2) also what is overriding stdout and std in ?

Comment: `stdout` is the standard output stream that `puts`, `printf` etc. write to.
`stdin` is the standard input stream for `gets' etc.  By `overriding` those you are re-directing the inputs and/or outputs of the affected process.

As for `execve`: when you call that, all execution of your program in the current process is stopped, and the program is replaced by something that behaves as if you had invoked the invocation that you've passed to execve on the command line-- except that it inherits any re-directions to `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` that you left in place (and some other details.)

Comment: so as I understand I will use execve in my program0 in order to inherit stdout from program1 to program2 then print it?